# Finding records that were inserted one week ago using split date and time fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with two fields called "date" and "time" which are given values when nte corresponding record got inserted into that row.

Is there a way I can look for any values in the table which were submitted a week ago?

Comment: A bit off-topic, but was there a particular reason date and time were split into two fields ?

Comment: I am just guessing here, but you probably split the date and time into seperate columns so you could more easily grab the entries for a single date. However, if you have a datetime field, you can use a query like WHERE DATE(datetimefield) = '2011-04-01' to accomplish the same thing. Just an FYI in case it helps.

Comment: @Wige A better solution would be to search `WHERE datetimefield BETWEEN '2011-04-01 00:00:00' and '2011-04-01 23:59:59'`.  The solution you suggested is not indexable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the date into MySQL format, so you would use the following:

```
$variable = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
```

If you don't need the value in your PHP script, you can also do it in your MySQL query using

```
date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that can help you

```
select concat_ws(' ',curdate(),time(now())) - interval 1 week
```

It can be written like this

```
select now() - interval 1 week
```

I've used concat_ws just to follow what you wrote with separated date and time.

Answer (score 1):

```
//This will get you the date for a week ago from now
$date = date();
$newdate = strtotime ( '-1 week' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );
```

Then do a select query using the $newdate variable in the where clause.

Comment: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'))` is a bit neater.

Answer (score 0):

PHP actually makes this really easy

```
strtotime("last Monday")
```

Comment: Last monday won't always be a week ago.

Comment: This is relative from now, but you can add the UNIX timestamp as a second parameter. @Toast: Maybe use `last week` then.

Comment: @toast - yeah like archimedix says - just pointing in the right direction